# How do I call an external php non WordPress class into functions.php?

Tags: php, functions, include

All my WordPress files are in:

```
/httpdocs/news/
```

and the classes I want to call are in:

```
/private/classes/
```

Would I use the include_once() function or is there a WordPress function? And how would I do it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your theme functions,

```
 <?php
    $includes_path = 'the root folder you want to call';
    require_once $includes_path . 'the_class_you_are_calling.php';
  ?>
```

Also make sure you have the privileges access... I know it's dummy but I've been there done that...